# C++ A small issue regarding function scope

Tags: c++, scope

I'm tackling this Tetris tutorial and so far understanding it piece by piece, but I have arrived at a point that has stumped me. This is the tutorial in question:

http://javilop.com/gamedev/tetris-tutorial-in-c-platform-independent-focused-in-game-logic-for-beginners/

My question regards a small issue of scope and functions. This is the Pieces class with the function in question, in a header file:

```
#ifndef _PIECES_
#define _PIECES_


class Pieces
{
public:

int GetBlockType        (int pPiece, int pRotation, int pX, int pY);
int GetXInitialPosition (int pPiece, int pRotation);
int GetYInitialPosition (int pPiece, int pRotation);
};

#endif // _PIECES_
```

Now here is the function GetBlockType() in a .cpp file.

```
int Pieces::GetBlockType (int pPiece, int pRotation, int pX, int pY)
{
    return mPieces [pPiece][pRotation][pX][pY];
}
```

The compiler tells me that `mPieces` is an undeclared identifier. There is a variable called `mPieces`, but I have declared it in main.cpp.

Is the problem an issue of scope? Have I declared `mPieces` in the wrong place? I've tried my hand at it and give up, so maybe someone here can help.

Comment: Your include guard name is a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). Anyway, functions cannot access variables that are local to other functions. That would cause so many unavoidable conflicts.

Comment: each cpp file is a separate compilation unit. If you want both `main.cpp` and `thisother.cpp` see `mPieces`, then you should declare it in a header file that both of those cpp files include. Why don't you make `mPieces` a member of the class?

Comment: This is interesting stuff. The comments section of this tutorial I'm following all claim that he did a great job explaining everything, yet I seem to be only one with this problem, so he must have done something right. I've tried what you guys have suggested and I just can't figure out what the problem is on my end.

Comment: Nobody can figure this out? There was an answer earlier and we were making headway but I guess the author must have deleted it since it's gone now.

Comment: The `pieces.cpp` file from the tutorial declares the `char mPieces` multi-dimenional array at the top of the file, above the `int Pieces::GetBlockType()` method. Does your `pieces.cpp` have that?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the source code and can see where there might be some confusion. In Main.cpp, the program declares an `mPieces` object, but it is an instance of the class Pieces. A pointer to that object is then used to initialize Board and Game instances.

**Main.cpp:**

```
// Pieces
Pieces mPieces;

// Board
Board mBoard (&mPieces, mScreenHeight);

// Game
Game mGame (&mBoard, &mPieces, &mIO, mScreenHeight);
```

So then we look into the header and implementation files of Pieces. In the header file, we do not see any reference to any sort of data structure - so it is still not clear where the `GetBlockType` function is finding mPieces.

When we look into Pieces.cc, we see the mPieces that `GetBlockType` references is actually a hard-coded 4-dimensional char array:

**Pieces.cpp:**

```
#include "Pieces.h"

// Pieces definition
char mPieces [7 /*kind */ ][4 /* rotation */ ][5 /* horizontal blocks */ ][5 /* vertical blocks */ ] =
{
    // all the possible positions
}

// irrelevant code omitted

int Pieces::GetBlockType (int pPiece, int pRotation, int pX, int pY)
{
    return mPieces [pPiece][pRotation][pX][pY];
}
```

The `char mPieces` array is actually declared in global scope, so it should be accessible by any part of the program subsequent to `#include "Pieces.h"`. In Main.cpp, the mPieces name is overridden in local scope by the `Pieces mPieces` declaration.

So now we see that in Main.cpp, mPieces is an instance of Pieces. The Pieces class itself, however, references a different mPieces - a char array that is defined in the Pieces.cpp class. You should verify that your Pieces.cpp has the correct mPieces array. I hope this helps!